# Dead code in eclipse when trying to find the sum of an array

Tags: java, loops, dead-code

I tried to find the sum of any array by using the for loop but the i++ part ended up being the deadcode unreachable. I don't understand why?

```
 public static int sum(int[] data) {
            int sum = 0;
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { //the i ++ is the deadcode
                    sum += data [i];
                    return sum;
                }
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: An unconditional return inside a loop pretty much never makes sense. After all, if you always return inside the loop then it will never loop at all and you might as well remove the loop. Because your loop always returns in the first iteration the i++ is never executed and dead code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `i++` is dead code because it can never be reached.  It can never be reached because you have a return statement within the loop.  Therefore, it will never execute the increment portion of the for-loop.  Move the `return sum;` outside the loop (replacing the `return 0;`).

```
public static int sum(int[] data) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    sum += data [i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't return something inside for loop, because return ends the cycle of whole function.

Instead, do something like this:

```java
    public static int sum(int[] data) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            sum += data[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are always returning after the first iteration so you do not sum anything besides the first element.
You should do it like this :

```
    public static int sum(int[] data) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        { 
                sum += data [i];

         }
        return sum;
    }

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int data[] = {1,2,3,4,5}; 
    int sum = sum(data);
    
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

}